# AWS CF Template for provisioning new EC2 instance with Existing Targetgroup

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-ec2-instance-connect

I'm trying to provision a new EC2 instance and attaching it to the existing **targetGroup** which I created earlier. I do have the *targetGroupArn*, and the new instance details. In all the documents, I could see the sample templates of creating a new instance and new **targetgroup** and referring the instance id to the creating **targetgroup**.

`Is there any option to create only new instance and attaching it to the existing target group?`

So that I can mention the *targetGroupArn* to which the new instances will be attaching.
Below I've mentioned the sample templates, what I'm looking for.

```
{
  "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup",
  "Properties": {
    "TargetGroupArn": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-south-1:4444444444:targetgroup/MyTG/56abcccccccc56",
    "Targets": [
      {
        "Id": {
          "Ref": "ec2Instance1"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Is there any option to do this by SDK approach instead of template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any option to create only new instance and attaching it to the existing target group?

Yes, you can do that through a [custom resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) in the form of a lambda function. The function would use AWS SDK, such as `boto3`, to attach the instances to the existing target group.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Here I dnt have the stack Id of the existing target group which I created earlier. I have only it's arn. So rather than updating the existing stack with the new instance details, I want an option to add the instances to the existing targetgroup with the targetgroup arn referance only...

Comment: I've updated my comments, please check.

Comment: @Sonu You can do whatever you want with `custom resources` because you program it yourself. Without `custom resources` you can't do what you want.

Comment: Hi, Is there any option to do this by SDK approach instead of template?   @Marcin

Comment: @Sonu Yes, your custom resource could use any AWS SDK you want, including AWS CLI. I would recommend to try to write that, and make new question if you have issue. Also acceptance of my answer would be appreciated if it was helpful.

Comment: With the custom resources, I'm able to do this.